# Regex how to get particular search within quotes

Tags: regex

I need to get a particular id from the quotes.

Input string is below

```
thecodeis = "3468337910";
```

expecting the output to be below

> 3468337910

I tried with couple of options but the closest I got was `.*`

Comment: what language is this ? are you just turning a string into a number ?  there are better ways that using regex if this is the case

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is close

```
".*"
```

But you if you only want the number you should capture it in a group with parenthesis

```
"(.*)"
```

What language are you using? Maybe we can help with syntax

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use "([\d])" as this will find any digits within the string.

If you can provide more details such as which language you are trying to do this within or if it is for a .htaccess file, then you should get a more specific response.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\d+` - it will capture *at least one digit* in the string.

Answer (score 0):

In **python**:

```
string = 'thecodeis = "34688337910";'
pattern =  'thecodeis\s*=\s*"([0-9]+)";'
re.findall(pattern, string)   // return ['34688337910']
```

If your input string has a different format, use this `pattern` instead:

```
pattern = '"([0-9])+"'
```

It will return all thes number between quotes in your page.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
"([^"]+?)"
```

**Explanation**

```
<!--
"([^"]+?)"

Options: case insensitive

Match the character “"” literally «"»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([^"]+?)»
   Match any character that is NOT a “"” «[^"]+?»
      Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «+?»
Match the character “"” literally «"»
-->
```